# Serialize JavaScript Error to Web API 2

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

I want to catch unhandled exceptions in a AngularJS app and send it via api to be able to log it.

Is there a object that the javascript error type serializes to in .Net?

```
 $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", ['$delegate', '$injector', function ($delegate, $injector) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            var $http = $injector.get("$http");
            var log = {
                error: exception,
                message: cause
            }
            $http.post('api/log', log)
            .finally(function () {
                //send to error page
            });
            $delegate(exception, cause);
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Are you talking about return the $http error if there is?

Comment: @Michelem Nope, I think there is a Error type in javascript similar to exceptions in C#. For example if you look at the documentation for `$exceptionHandler` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler you'll notice it takes a argument of type `Error` named `exception`.

Also described here it seems https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dww52sbt(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: you probably have to use the try/catch statement that returns an error object